# svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: macos, svn, unix, terminal

I'm trying to svn checkout this library https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout but my svn doesn't connect from a particular macbook, same internet connection but different macbook it is able to checkout successfully

I get:
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com)

What setting could be different on a macbook that can cause this ? Both computers have same OSX, Xcode and svn versions.

It doesn't connect to other repositories either that are hosted on code.google.com

Comment: Do you solved your problem?! i have same :/

Comment: @Mr.Hyde scroll down and read my answer

Comment: So that's not work for me :/. Now i'm using this brilliant https://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/releases/view/54881

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The culprit was Cisco AnyConnect, I uninstalled it and svn works

Comment: @farmer1992 well I just started thinking of changes I had done on my computer lately & reverse engineered the culprit :)

Comment: wow, this is most likely the weirdest thing I needed to do to fix a computer issue ;-)

Comment: Have to admit, I was skeptical, but this also worked for me.  I was connecting to a internal repository, so it's not limited to google hosted svn repositories.  Highly annoying.  FWIW, I'm on OSX 10.9. I forgot to check the Cisco Client version before removing it.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, I also had cisco anyconnect, but my solution was to change the URL to https and it seemed to work.

That is I edited

**http**://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn

to

**https**://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn

in the script file

Comment: What is the path to the script file?

Comment: This works for me. Changed http://<<>>.googlecode.com/svn/ to https://<<>>.googlecode.com/svn/

Comment: Can someone please mention which script file here?

Answer (score 2):

I removed all the previous auth ssl server by the command:

`rm ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/*`

and all worked again.

Comment: This was the short and easy answer for me. Saved me hours of miserable debugging :)

Comment: It worked for me once, months ago. But not today. I remove the files inside that directory and Eclipse + SVN still complains :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the solution was different for me. I had upgraded to a new Netbeans (version 8) and had selected two different directories. None of the other answers here were relevant and I was already using https so I entered my auth info (although it's not required for c/o here) and just chose 1 directory root at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, had to uninstall Cisco AnyConnect and it works. But if you need both then uninstall Cisco VPN and re-install it without the "Web Security" component.

Running both Syncro and Cisco AnyConnect.

Answer (score 0):

Steps what I did to solve the problem:

- I turned off my internet connection
- I cleared my DNS cache by running the command on my mac `dscacheutil -flushcache`
- And then tried `svn update` and it worked this time

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected my internet connection and re-connected it again. This resolved the problem. After this, I repeated the process of importing the project from SVN & was able to do it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When I used homebrew to install, I had this problem too.

I changed the formula URL from `https` to `http` and it worked.

The path in my book is `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/`