# How to fix E175002: Options error?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am facing the `E175002: Options` error while trying to access my SVN server. I get this error when I am trying to add it to my SVN repositories in Eclipse, opening the synchronisation view or update/commit.

> Synchronize operation failed.
>
> svn: E175002: OPTIONS of '/svn/MySVN/branches/my.project': 500 Internal Server Error (IP)
>
> svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/MySVN/branches/my.project'

I can access the repository through my internet browser, so the server can't be offline.

I looked inside the files of `/data/svn/MySVN/conf` without editing anything. Also I checked `config` and `servers` inside `/etc/subversion`. All lines are commented.

What could I try to fix the error?

Comment: Can you see if the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033706/243373) shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> What could I try to fix the error?

Nothing, I guess. :)

`500 Internal Server Error` is the server-side error and I doubt that you can do anything to solve it except to **contact the server's system administrator**.

Comment: I am the server's administrator. :P  The files I have checked are on the server. But I don't really know that much about the structure of it...

Comment: @John Then check the server log. It should contain events logged when you get the error on the client side. These errors should help you identifying the root cause.

Comment: Which one would you recommend to check in this case?

Comment: @John The log of Apache HTTP Server that makes your repos available through HTTP(S) using `mod_dav_svn` module.